# Is the following function concave? Where does it attain its minimum?Its maximum?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, polyhedra

Consider the function

$f: \{1 , \ldots, m\} \times \Delta^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where

\begin{equation}
\Delta^{m}:=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{m} \ | \ \sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i = 1 , \ \lambda_j \geq 0 \text{ for } j=1, \ldots m \}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f(j,\lambda)=\langle y^{(j)}, \sum _{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i x^{(i)}-z \rangle 
\end{equation}

For some $y^{s} \in  \mathbb{R}^{n} \text{ for } s=1, \ldots, m, \ z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $x^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \text{ for } i=1, \ldots m . $

**Question**: Is the function $F :  \Delta^{m} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{m}$

\begin{equation}
F(\lambda) = \underset{j=1, \ldots, m }{\min} f(j,\lambda)
\end{equation}

concave? Where does it attain its minimum (as a function of $\lambda$ of course)? Please consider first my attempt before answering, and tell me where I am wrong (if I am). Additional question: where does it attain its maximum?

**Attempt**: I know that the pointwise minimum of a set of concave function is again concave. So it would be enough to show that $f(j,\lambda)$ is concave, to then conclude that the minimum is attained at some vertex $v_i=(0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$ where $1$ is in the $i^{\text{th}}$ position. My argument for concavity is:

\begin{gather} 
f(j, \alpha(\lambda^{(1)}) + (1-\alpha)(\lambda^{(2)}))=\langle y^{(j)}, \alpha \sum _{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i^{(1)} x^{(i)}+(1-\alpha)\sum _{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i ^{(2)}x^{(i)}-(1-\alpha)z-\alpha z \rangle \\ 
=(1-\alpha) \langle y^{(j)}, \sum _{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i^{(1)} x^{(i)}-z \rangle + \alpha \langle y^{(j)}, \sum _{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i^{(2)} x^{(i)}-z \rangle  \\ 
= \alpha f(j, \lambda^{(1)}) + (1-\alpha)f(j,\lambda^{(2)}),
\end{gather} 
where $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $\lambda^{(1)}, \lambda^{(2)} \in \Delta^{m}$.

Comment: Hello - your overall argument and the detailed argument for  each $f(j, \cdot)$  are all sound. Note that by setting $X$ to be the matrix with column $x^{(j)}$ and then $w_j = (y^{(j)})^TX, c_j = \langle y^{j},z\rangle$  you can write $f(j,\lambda) = w_j \lambda - c_j$. Thus these functions are affine. That's what you argument is showing. The minimum of $F$ may then be found with linear programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(\lambda) = f(j,\lambda)$ is concave in $\lambda$, and the minimum of concave functions is concave.

By the maximum principle, a concave function is minimized at an extreme point of the domain, which is the argument for your choice $v_i$.

Comment: What about the maximum?Is it true that a conave function attains its maximum at a vertex? If so, could you point me to some references?

Comment: A concave function can attain its maximum anywhere in the domain (interior and boundary). Linear optimization is your friend.

Comment: you have an idea how to find the maximum of $F(\lambda)$?

Comment: @sigmatau do you have matlab?

Comment: yes, but I'm more interested to know from a theoretical point of view, because I would like to analyze the complexity of an algorithm and maximizing $F$ over a convex polytope is one step of the algorithm.Btw thank you for your time.

Comment: If you formulate it as a linear optimization problem ($\max_{\lambda,t} \{t : t \leq f(j,\lambda) \forall j\}$), there is complexity theory from interior point methods.